# How to display a new component on click of next button in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a form Component, i am doing validation of that form on click of the Next button, once the validation will be successful i want to render a different component.

inside the state i am keeping the "showComponent" as false and on the click of that button i am making it true.

```
_onButtonClick (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        showComponent:  !this.state.showComponent
    })
    console.log("button clicked",this.state);
  }
```

Button Logic :

```
<div>
    <button onClick={(event) => this._onButtonClick(event)}>Button</button>
         {this.state.showComponent ?<AddModules /> : null}
</div>
```

I am able to render that new page but its rendering on the same page, which i don't want.

Comment: I believe you probably didn't use the `exact` keyword when declaring your Component via the `<Route />` component.  Make sure when declaring your route to only load a component when the route matches an exact path to declare it like so: <Route exact path='/My/Path' component={MyComponent} />

Comment: Thanks, i had done that but path issue was there, thnx for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the`<Route />` component that `react-router-dom` gives you is exactly what you need.

Take a look at the [example in the react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic). Notice how they set up their `<Route />`. They also have an [example in the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions) on how to prevent someone from going into another page.

I also made a quick [demo in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pkknx5nllq) that more closely resembles what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, i had done that but path issue was there, thnx for your guidance and specially thanx for the demo, can you tell me if how to pass an object from the first component to other component and vice versa. So that both the objects i can store in a parent object and can save in DB.

Comment: You should be able to use the `render` or `children` props in the `<Route />` ([see docs here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)). This allows you to render as your normally would in JSX, and not just pass a component in.

Take a look at this [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6rq6760pk) that shows two components in different routes sharing the same data.

Comment: On clicking Back button, is it possible to display what the user typed in the previous page before? 'Value 2'?